# cmake use wildcard for find_library NAMES option

Tags: cmake, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

In cmake to find a library we use `find_library(MyLibrary_LIBRARY NAMES mylibrary mylibrary10 mylibrary11 HINTS /path/to/library)`. This command tells cmake to find a file named `mylibrary.so` or `mylibrary10.so` or `mylibrary11.so` (or files with `.lib` suffix in windows) per path of `HINTS`. If any of the above files were found, the path to the file would be written to the `MyLibrary_LIBRARY` variable. However, as one of the libraries I am using is frequently being updated - so that the library would soon be renamed to `mylibrary20.so` or `mylibrary21.so` - I need to update the cmake script frequently to reflect the changes. I wonder if there is a way that I can use wildcard here, so that cmake would automatically find `mylibraryXX.so` here, where `XX` means two digits.

According to documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html), it seems this is not supported. If that's the case, will there be any other workarounds? (Creating a link from `mylibraryXX.so` to `mylibrary.so` doesn't quite work for me, as I don't have control of the library.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for wildcard in the `find_library` and other `find_*` commands.

If name of the library is not fixed, then it is normal to enumerate all possible names in `NAMES` option.

For example, script [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) collects all known versions of Boost in a variable:

```
set(_Boost_KNOWN_VERSIONS ${Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS}
    "1.74.0" "1.74"
    "1.73.0" "1.73" "1.72.0" "1.72" "1.71.0" "1.71" "1.70.0" "1.70" "1.69.0" "1.69"
    "1.68.0" "1.68" "1.67.0" "1.67" "1.66.0" "1.66" "1.65.1" "1.65.0" "1.65"
    # ...
    "1.34" "1.33.1" "1.33.0" "1.33")
```

and create list of possible library names by iterating over this variable.

Note, that while the list of known versions is hardcoded, `FindBoost.cmake` allows (by means of `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` variable) a user to specify additional versions, which could be not known for the script at the time it is written.

For create a list of possible library names with two-digits version suffix, you may use [foreach(RANGE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) loop:

```
set(mylibrary_names)
foreach(ver RANGE 11 99)
  list(APPEND mylibrary_names mylibrary${ver})
endforeach()

find_library(MyLibrary_LIBRARY NAMES ${mylibrary_names})
```

Note, that changing library name usually implies some incompatibility, so blindly iterating over all virtually possible versions of the library may cause you program to not work as expected.